# Is SQL Server CE 4 in a VS2010 WinForms application possible?

Tags: sql-server-ce-4

I'm trying to use SQL CE 4 via Entity Framework 4 in a WinForm application. Can anybody answer if this combination is possible?

Comment: See my own question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381651/entity-data-model-wizard-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-lacks-support-for-entitysqlser

Answer (score 1):

Ye, it is possible, but the EDM Wizard does not support this combination. You can use my SQL Server Compact toolbox add-in to create a EDMX in your class library or winforms projects