# Entity Data Model wizard in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 lacks support for EntitySQLServerCompact 4.0 in non ASP.Net projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I finally found some resources and a solution. I will share it here.

Comment: When asking a question that you're going to answer yourself, make the question sound like an actually question. Not, "I know how to do this". It's more search worthy that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx) that this indeed is a feature and not a bug.

In [this excellent series of blogs](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html) you can find anything you always wanted to know, but never dared to ask about SQLServerCompact 4.0

The author of these blogs has made a [wonderful Add-In for Visual Studio 2010](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) that adds Entity Data Model wizard functionality to create a model from a SQLServerCompact 4.0 database for any type of project.